# MacBook Air 2015 - power button hasn't been working?

Tags: macbook-pro, power

So I have an early 2015 MacBook Air and haven't used it in months due to it not turning on (even though the charging light was on)

It's been months as I said so tonight I thought I'd try turning it on again and to my surprise, it booted up fine when pressing the power button.
I stupidly turned off the MacBook so I could factory reset it and now I can't get it back on at all as the power button is completely unresponsive. Again I can see it's charging. I've tried the SMC reset but don't think it works as you need to hold the power button to do the reset...

I can't really afford to get it fixed and want to try sorting it out myself as it worked fine tonight until I turned it off.

I noticed the battery was at 0% and so do you think I need to wait for the battery to discharge?

I don't have the tools to open up the MacBook and am extremely impractical.

Comment: Also see [Power button not working on Macbook PRO 13" 2013 - ideas on how to reset SMC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/321218/119271) for info on how to reset the SMC when you can’t use the power button

Comment: As per the linked dupe, if your battery was reading zero and it won’t charge, then it may be acting as a power drain.  Try disconnecting the battery then powering up with mains connected.  If this is out if your skillset, you’ll have to take it in for repairs.

Comment: Thanks. My battery was charging fine. When if started, unexpectedly, it was 0% but it charged up to 35% by the time I shut it down. I was wondering if it will only start if battery is dead and plugged in.

Comment: Your battery may not be holding a charge or your power button just coincidentally failed.  If you happen to turn it on again, go into power settings and set it to turn on at a time like 7:00am every day to get around the button problem

Comment: That was my exact plan. Looks like I'll need to get it looked at and repaired. So strange the power button worked earlier! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Post your fix as an answer when you get it resolved. Ping me in comments (@Allan) here so I get notified and I can upvote.