# How to disconnect MacBook Pro 15 2017 battery?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I'm struggling to figure out how to "unplug" or disconnect the battery of my retina MacBook Pro 15' 2017 from its logic board, to reset the SMC.

What cable(s) do I need to disconnect exactly?

Those?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your keyboard not working?  If not, use a *generic wired USB keyboard* to reset the SMC.

Comment: @Allan, the keyboard is working fine, the thing is, the power button does not work, as the logicboard "think" that the battery is at 0% and refuse to boot, so I can't reset SMC with keystrokes...

Comment: Got it.  However, it's highly unlikely that the SMC isn't working properly.  Your battery may be a faulty unit (it happens).  With a MBP so new, I would take it in and let Apple deal with it (they also have a keyboard replacement program)

Comment: @Allan You were right, I even broke the battery connector in the process, so when I powered my mbp up again, it was like there were no battery anymore... I ended up bringing it to an applestore! Thank you for your help anyway:)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it helps to look at the replacement part to see what connectors it has.

[image: MacBook Pro 15" 2016/2017 Battery]

From this picture, we can see that there is a PCB and a small connector cable at the top of the assembly.

This would correspond to this part in your photo

[image: Battery connector]

Disconnect that, and your SMC should reset.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a little research **before** stripping your machine & invalidating any remaining warranty might have been more sensible.
You don't need to disconnect the battery.

You also need to know **why** you may need to reset it.

Most times it's not the fix... https://support.apple.com/HT201295

> ## What the SMC does
>
> The SMC is responsible for these and other low-level functions on
> Intel-based Mac computers:
>
> - Responding to presses of the power button
> - Responding to the display lid opening and closing on Mac notebooks
> - Battery management
> - Thermal management
> - Sudden Motion Sensor (SMS)
> - Ambient light sensing
> - Keyboard backlighting
> - Status indicator light (SIL) management
> - Battery status indicator lights
> - Selecting an external (instead of internal) video source for some iMac displays
>
> ## How to know if you need to reset the SMC
>
> These symptoms might mean that an SMC reset is necessary:
>
> - Your computer's fans run at high speed, even though it isn't under heavy usage and is properly ventilated.
> - The keyboard backlight behaves incorrectly.
> - The status indicator light, if present, behaves incorrectly.
> - Battery indicator lights, if present, behave incorrectly on Mac notebooks with a non-removable battery.
> - The display backlight doesn't respond correctly to ambient light changes.
> - Your Mac doesn't respond when you press the power button.
> - Your Mac notebook doesn't respond properly when you close or open the lid.
> - Your Mac sleeps or shuts down unexpectedly and you can't turn it back on.
> - The battery doesn't charge properly.
> - Your MacBook or MacBook Pro doesn't charge through its built-in USB-C port.
> - Your MacBook or MacBook Pro doesn't recognize external devices that are connected to its built-in USB-C port.
> - The MagSafe power adapter LED, if present, doesn't indicate the correct charging activity.
> - Your Mac performs unusually slowly, even though its CPU isn't under an abnormally heavy load.
> - A Mac that supports target display mode doesn't switch into or out of target display mode as expected, or it switches into or out of
>   target display mode at unexpected times.
> - The illumination around the I/O ports on a Mac Pro (Late 2013) doesn't turn on when you move the computer.
>
> ## Before you reset the SMC
>
> Try each of these steps in this order before you reset the SMC. Test
> the issue after each step to see if the issue still occurs.
>
> 1. If your Mac isn't responding, press and hold the power button until it shuts down. You'll lose unsaved work in any open applications. Then
>    press the power button again to turn on your Mac.
> 2. Press Command-Option-Escape to force quit any application that's not responding.
> 3. Put your Mac to sleep by choosing Apple () menu >Sleep. Wake the computer after it's gone to sleep.
> 4. Restart your Mac by choosing Apple menu >Restart.
> 5. Shut down your Mac by choosing Apple menu > Shut Down, then press the power button again to turn on your Mac.
>
> If you're using a Mac notebook that's having power or battery issues,
> follow these steps:
>
> 1. Unplug the power adapter from your Mac and the electrical outlet for several seconds, then plug it back in.
> 2. Choose Apple menu > Shut Down.
> 3. After your Mac shuts down, remove and re-insert the battery if it's removable.
> 4. Press the power button again to turn on your Mac.
> 5. If the issue still isn't resolved, you might need to reset the SMC using the steps below.
>
> ## How to reset the SMC on Mac notebooks
>
> To reset the SMC on a Mac notebook, first determine whether the
> battery is removable. Most older Mac notebooks have removable
> batteries. Mac notebooks that have nonremovable batteries include
> MacBook Pro (Early 2009 and later), all models of MacBook Air, MacBook
> (Late 2009), and MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, Early 2015 and later).
>
> If the battery is nonremovable:
>
> 1. Choose Apple menu > Shut Down.
> 2. After your Mac shuts down, press Shift-Control-Option on the left side of the built-in keyboard, then press the power button at the same
>    time. Hold these keys and the power button for 10 seconds. If you have
>    a MacBook Pro with Touch ID, the Touch ID button is also the power
>    button.
> 3. Release all keys.
> 4. Press the power button again to turn on your Mac.
>
> If the battery is removable:
>
> 1. Shut down your Mac.
> 2. Remove the battery. If you need help removing the battery, contact an Apple Authorized Service Provider or Apple Retail Store.
> 3. Press and hold the power button for 5 seconds.
> 4. Reinstall the battery.
> 5. Press the power button again to turn on your Mac.

Comment: A point of clarification:  In the US, the [Magnuson-Moss Act](https://mlmlaw.com/library/guides/ftc/warranties/undermag.htm) prohibits companies from voiding warranties if you open up your device.  If you break something, that's another matter.  However, if you open it up, change the battery and the keyboard fails (as they're doing now), Apple cannot void your warranty.

Comment: A point of sense: don't just take the darn thing apart before actually working out what you really need to do to fix the issue you are having. US law doesn't cover 96% of the world's population. I suspect an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: @Tetsujin You were right, I even broke the battery connector, so when I powered my mbp up again, it was like there were no battery anymore... I ended up bringing it to an applestore!