# MacBook Pro 15-inches display not working: how to isolate the cause of the issue?

Tags: display, disk-utility, power-management, thunderbolt-display, nvram

On last Saturday I left my MacBook Pro (15-inches display, mid-2012 release) on during the night in order to finish some backup tasks and I scheduled its shutdown for a certain time using `shutdown -h`.

On the next morning, I turned the machine back on but, unfortunately, the display seemed to not work. First of all, supposing the issue was due to some software level failures during shutdown, I have made the following operations:

1. NVRAM/PRAM reset.
2. SMC reset.
3. File system analysis.
   I was using two APFS containers - one for a data-only partition, the other for different OS partitions with shared memory - and Disk Utility printed some warnings related to the main OS partition.
4. Considering what has been just said, main OS partition initialization and clean macOS High Sierra reinstalling.

Despite all these operations, the issue still persists: the main display does not turn on but everything else works properly (for instance, using an external display through Thunderbolt connection, all seems fine).

That said, are there some other operations that you suggest to do in order to isolate and find the cause of  this issue? Since it seems, taking into account what I listed above, that it is not related to software layer, are there some simple checks that can be made on machine hardware without particular risk to generate further issues?

Comment: With the external display, can you try to go in System Preferences > Energy > Uncheck "Automatic graphics switching" ?

Comment: Do you the Apple logo while booting?  If you hold down the `Opt` ket while booting, does the boot manger interface appear?

Comment: What were the “warnings?”  Its a massive jump to go from an unknown error in `diskutil`  to “it’s the software layer.”  I wrote an answer on [resetting NVRAM/SMC and reinstalling the OS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/390654/119271). (Second part of answer) as part of the repair procedure. Its worth a read.

Comment: @Lulucmy, I already did that before reinstalling OS. Nothing changed, unfortunately.

Comment: @Allan, it is not just a black screen but it doesn't even turn on (no light signs are visible even in a fully dark environment). Anyway, answering to your question about warnings, I did not log them and, sincerely, I don't remember anything about them if not that they were several messages and that they were printed only when launching Disk Utility from external USB drive and deactivating disk partition.

Comment: If it doesn’t turn on before macOS boots, its not software.  Your display died and it needs to be serviced.

Comment: @Allan, are there some procedures to validate the display death? I am asking for this information because - as far as I have read - it is pretty uncommon that displays stop working suddenly without previous symptoms, isn't it?

Comment: Yes.  You plug it into a known working source.  Unless you have a spare MacBook lying around, you have to take it in.  But you can be pretty certain its the display because you're not seeing anything prior to macOS loading.   Displays die;  it’s possible it’s only the backlight. It’s not uncommon especially with older machines.

Comment: If it is just a backlight issue, it is reasonable to think that by placing a light beam from the rear Apple logo, something should appear on the screen?  I'm asking for this hint just to do a last check.

Comment: Yeah, that would confirm a backlight issue